# Brewferm Abdijbier + buckwheat honey = a bit of a bitter flavour - Help please

Tags: honey

I have made one Brewferm beer before (the Grand Cru which turned out very well) and in an attempt to run before I could walk, when I came to make the other one I had (the Abdijbier) I thought it would be nice to replicate a buckwheat honey beer I had in Poland, so decided to exchange some of the sugar added at the fermentation stage for buckwheat honey.  I replaced about 1/3 - 1/4 of the sugar with honey and checked to make sure I had the correct OG as indicated on the instruction sheet.

The brew has been in a bucket with lid and airlock for a couple of weeks and I've just transferred it to a second bucket for clarification.  The SG is around 1.016 and there hasn't been much sign of bubbles over the last few days, so I'm not sure if it has reached a point where it is stuck and won't get to the recommended optimal bottling density of 1.010.  However, my main concern is that on tasting it, it is a bit bitter. Is it best just to leave it for a bit and see if it mellows, or could I add a bit more sugar at this stage to sweeten it up a bit? Any thoughts? Is it too early to panic, or the right time to act?

Comment: can you add the recipe for the second recipe that is bitter? usually time will let it mellow.

Comment: there wasn't really a recipe - heat the malt in the can and pour into a bucket and add water and sugar (some of which I replaced with honey).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a pre hopped can of malt..... So its probably the can of malt with hops adding more bitterness then expected. I would let it sit, and it should mellow out. if not you could add some un hopped wort.....

but I would do is let it sit and mellow out....

RDWHAHB
(relax, don't worry, have a home brew)

also from brewferm

Brewferm beers are strong, aromatic beers and therefore usually require a longer maturation
time (6 to 8 weeks). Always respect this period. Your patience will be rewarded by incomparable beer quality.